# Find Selected Radio Button Value Based on Multiple Attribute Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 different Radio Buttons in a page with the following code

```
<input type="radio" name"1" value="1">1</input>

<input type="radio" name"2" value="2">2</input>

<input type="radio" name"3" value="3">3</input>
```

How can I get the value of the selected radio button with different names ?

I tried

```
var option = $("input[type='radio'][name='1']:checked").val();
```

But giving Undefined. Any Idea's ?

Comment: Is it checked when you try to use that selector, or unchecked? At what point do you try to use the selector, in response to what event, or change? Also you have invalid html, the `input` element is self-closing.

Comment: every thing is working fine execept I have to select the value of selected radio button value with multiple attribue selection

Comment: input type radio don't need `</input>` at the end.. it is self-closing

Comment: @user2971263 make a fiddle or is your code live?? Check console for errors .

Answer (score 0):

You need to have them be the same name, otherwise they don't work as radios (they could all be selected), and you need your html to be valid:

```
 <input type="radio" name="1" value="1">1
 <input type="radio" name="1" value="2">2
 <input type="radio" name="1" value="3">3
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `=` when assigning the `name` attribute.

```
<input type="radio" name="1" value="1" />
                  <!--  ^
```

Also, as others have pointed out in comments, `input` tags are self-closing. (although it does work even with invalid html)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g7RT2/

Answer (score 0):

You missed "=" sign after the "name" attribute, selector doesn't match name=1 condition: `<input type="radio" name"1" value="1">1</input>`
http://jsfiddle.net/gLgBj/

Answer (score 0):

here is a working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mW7mk/

your html is not well formated, the input is self closed and name="1" not name"1"

```
   var options = $("input[type='radio'][name='1']:checked").val();
   alert("test : " + options);
```

worked just fine with :

```
   <label><input type="radio" name="1" value="1" checked="checked"/>1</label>
   <label><input type="radio" name="2" value="2"/>2</label>
   <label><input type="radio" name="3" value="3"/>3</label>
```